# Fast access to a MATLAB array of structs based on its id

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a Matlab struct:

```
a(1).x=54.23; a(1).y=2.3; a(1).col=32.221; a(1).id=1;
a(2).x=5.23; a(2).y=3.3; a(2).col=2.221; a(2).id=2;
```

... and so on. Now i want to access the struct in `a` having id 73. I can think of doing a for loop but the thing is i have to access elements of array `a` several times like this based on id. Wat is the fastest data structure available for this purpose? Python like dictionary may work but i am not sure ow to implement it. Pointing out some code examples would be very helpful.

Comment: Why not `a(73)`?

Comment: Actually id can be any integer. id may not correspond to the element number in the array.

Comment: Then you probably want a [map container](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
id=[a.id];
a(id==73)
```

It's not as efficient as a dictionary, but if it's fast enough for your purposes it's not worth looking further.

The `a.id` part evaluates to a comma-separated list of id values, which are concatenated in an array that you can then use for lookup.