# fast access of an element in struct array based on multple criteria

Tags: arrays, matlab, search, matlab-struct

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43268460/4023805) last time. Answers there were very helpful. I want to suggest a slight variant. I need to access that element of a `struct` array which has `a(i).x==5.65 && a(i).y==32.23`?

Again i can run the good old `for` loop and find the index of required element but i have to make such queries multiple time. What is the fastest data structure to do this? What method should i use to search through the `struct` array to find the desired element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dot indexing to yield a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) and then coerce that into an array. You can then perform logical operations on the resulting array to yield a `logical` array that you can use to then index into your `struct` array

```
b = a([a.x] == 5 & [a.y] == 32)
```